# JavaScript eval() fails with window.external.notify(), works with window.alert()

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8, internet-explorer-10

On WP8, if I execute (1):

```
Microsoft.Phone.WebBrowser wb;
wb.InvokeScript("eval", "window.external.notify('abc');");
```

It throws a 'target of invocation returned an error', unknown error, hresult 80020101.
But (2)

```
wb.InvokeScript("eval", "window.alert('abc');");
```

works fine, and displays the message box.

And (3)

```
wb.InvokeScript("eval", "( function (){window.external.notify('abc');})();");
```

Also works fine.

My question is, what is it about window.external.notify() that prevents eval from invoking it directly?  It is a function call, like window.alert(), so it should be a valid script.  But if there is something special about the unadorned call in 1), then why does the wrapped call in 3) work?

I understand that eval() is the root of all evil, and I have read other SO posts relating to eval() problems with a function definition.  (Where would we all be without SO?) But this is clearly a different problem.

Comment: This may be related to whatever is in your HTML. It might be trigger quirks mode or similar. Can you show a full repro of the issue?

Comment: Thank you for providing the wokraround in (3). God bless you.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is related with context of calling that `eval(...)`.

If you call `eval("window.external.notify('abc');")`, the script should be called on the global `window` context.

You can check the context as below to pring the current context:

`eval("console.log(this); window.external.notify('abc');")`

Then try to test in those 3 ways to check is there any difference about the context.

To specify one context to run, you can use `call` or `apply` to set context with first param.

Answer (score 0):

For executing JavaScript code in WebView from C# use InvokeScript and getting values from java script functions in C# use window.external.notify in java script function.
to catch value in C# from java script functions use following code.

```
private void Web_OnScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Called from ScriptNotify! {0}", new[] { e.Value });
}
```